# How to use regex to match object key and replace with its value?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I'm still new with Javascript and I'm not entirely sure how to go about this.

I want it to match the key field and replace it with its value.

```
const state = {
"NY": "New York"
}
```

**You live in NY** 
to
**You live in New York**

The list is going to be quite long with all the states so I think I'll have to use objects. 
Any help would be appreciated! Thank you in advance!

EDIT>>>

Thank you so much to those that replied! 
I made a list of all the states for USA, Canada, and Mexico to their full name here:
https://gist.github.com/PepperAddict/b8c6c80af4a17908fd98378b4375047e

using the code that was provided, I was able to change them all to their full name.

Thank you thank you thank you!

Comment: `Object.keys(state).forEach(k => str = str.replace(k, state[k]))`

Comment: `You live in ${arrayOfStates['NY']}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need regex, use the keys from the object `state`

```
Object.keys(state).forEach(k => str = str.replace(k, state[k]));
```

```js
const state = { "NY": "New York" };
var str = "You live in NY";

Object.keys(state).forEach(k => str = str.replace(k, state[k]));
console.log(str);
```

**Using regex to replace the whole set of matches:**

```js
const state = { "NY": "New York" };
var str = "You live in NY and again in NY";

Object.keys(state).forEach(k => str = str.replace(new RegExp(`\\b${k}\\b`, 'g'), state[k]));
console.log(str);
```

Comment: Wow. This worked beautifully!!!
I had a feeling I was overcomplicating this.  Thank you!!!

Comment: Only downside here is that it will only work with a single instance of each state. If it shows up more than once, the later instances will not be replaced. For that, you either need a while loop or regex

Comment: I've added an answer that shows the regex solution that will handle all replacements

Answer (score 1):

We can make use of template literals and map it will return an array which you can then do what you want with.

```js
const state = {
"NY": "New York"
}
console.log(Object.keys(state).map(s => `You live in ${state[s]}`))
```

If you're planning to do this with a user for example

---

```js
const state = {
"NY": "New York"
}
const user = {
 name: "joe",
 state: "NY",
 liveIn: () => `You live in ${state[user.state]}`
}
console.log(user.liveIn())
```

Answer (score 1):

if you are sure the last word is `key`. Then you can skip **foreach** by following.

```
const state = {
"NY": "New York"
}

var a = "You live in NY";

b = a.split(" ");

b = b[b.length - 1];


a.replace(b, state[b]);

Console.log(a);
```

**Output**

```
"You live in New York"
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const states = {
  "CA": "California",
  "NY": "New York"
}

var input = "I'm from CA, thinking of moving to NY but not sure, I still really like CA."

var regexStr = Object.keys(states).join("|")
var statesRgx = new RegExp(`\\b(${regexStr})\\b`, 'g')
console.log(statesRgx)
function stateReplace(str){
  return str.replace(statesRgx, val => states[val])
}

console.log(stateReplace(input))
```